# Is it possible to get permanent links out of a OneDrive folder?

Tags: php, rest, curl, onedrive, image-gallery

I'm trying to create a gallery out of OneDrive images. 
However I'm not finding any way to get permanent links to folder files.

Actually I get files through

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/'. $folder_id .'/children
```

But no reference to any direct link. I tried using **@microsoft.graph.downloadUrl** key, but it is temporary.

Is there any way to achieve this or I thrown two days down the drain?

Comment: No it is not possible - both downloadUrl and thumbnailUrls are temporary. I was using old SkyDrive API which had so called pre-authenticated urls, but new API does not support it anymore.

Comment: The only way to achieve that is to store locally the authentication token that you receive when you authenticate yourself and attach it to every request.

Comment: Thanks. So, I literally wasted two days :P